# Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object Помогите

Tags: php, обработка-ошибок

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\models\news.php on line 22

Вот сам news.php

```
<?php

class News
{
    public static function getNewsList() // Возвращает одну новость по ID
    {
          $host = 'localhost';
          $dbname = 'mvc_site';
          $user = 'root';
          $password = '';
          $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $password);

          $newsList = array();

          $result = $db->query('SELECT id, title, date, short_content'
                    . 'FROM news'
                    . 'ORDER BY date DESC'
                    . 'LIMIT 10');

          $i = 0;

          while ($row = $result->fetch()){
              $newsList[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
              $newsList[$i]['title'] = $row['title'];
              $newsList[$i]['date'] = $row['date'];
              $newsList[$i]['short_content'] = $row['short_content'];
              $i++;

          }
          return $newsList;       
    }


}
```

Comment: _PDO::query() возвращает объект PDOStatement или **FALSE**, если запрос выполнить не удалось._ - так что, возможно запрос выполнить не удалось

Comment: Скажите, а почему вы не воспользовались для начала поиском http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Call+to+a+member+function+fetch%28%29+on+a+non-object   ?

Comment: @Grundy причем `false` возвращается по простой причине: потому что вместе склеены `news` и `ORDER`, `content` и `FROM`, `DESC` и `LIMIT`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

У вас в результате запроса возвращается `false`. Отсюда и ошибка.

`false` возвращается потому, что у вас это:

```
'SELECT id, title, date, short_content'
. 'FROM news'
. 'ORDER BY date DESC'
. 'LIMIT 10'
```

Превращается в:

`SELECT id, title, date, short_contentFROM newsORDER BY date DESCLIMIT 10`

То, что вы в редакторе выводите информацию по клавише <kbd>Enter</kbd> не значит, что он и в запросе разделит их хоть как-то. Это разные вещи совсем

Итог: добавьте по пробелу на каждой новой строке. Или в конце.

Comment: Спасибо большое, я думал я поставил пробел  после short_content и перед кавычкой. Спасибо большое.

Comment: @Сергей не только после `short_content`, но и на каждой другой нужен пробел

Comment: та да, я видел)) спасибо)

Comment: Вы можете галочку поставить, не стесняйтесь)